# total row count of parent group (summarize total)

Tags: ssrs-2012, rdlc

I have a table which has 2 groups and the second group is nested from first like so

```
Parent - Child -  Col
X          X1     xx
                  xx
           X2     xx
                  xx
                  xx
---------------------
Y          Y1     yy
                  yy
```

I only care about getting the count of Cols For each parent group
like This is the desired result

```
Parent - Child -  Col
X          X1     xx
                  xx
           X2     xx
                  xx
                  xx
Total     :   5
----------------------
Y          Y1     yy
                  yy
Total     :   2
```

I actually managed to get total of Child group using expression =Count(Fields!Col.Value) by putting cell inside any of the 2 groups and I tried to sum it by clicking on it and choose total but it do it for all table not the parent group

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's the `2` that you can't get?

If so then you can get this by counting the number of distinct Parents

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Parent.Value, "myDataSetName")
```

`"myDataSetName"` is the name of the dataset you are counting from, it is case sensitive and must be enclosed in quotes.